# Multi language SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, customization, multilingual

I'm developing a SharePoint site with multi-language feature.
My customer whants that when the language is changed, not only the labels are going to be traslated, but also the content: list contents, for example links descriptions, web part titles, announcements content, etc... (he's supposed to insert the content for all the languages the SharePoint site supports). How can I achieve this?
Thanks a lot

Ale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only out-of-the-box option I can think of is variations. More info on this page: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2010/04/12/variations-in-sharepoint-2010-connecting-people-with-content.aspx